# Trying to attach files PDF one by one

Tags: python

I have some files that i need send to some companies and i'm trying send one by one, but for some reason he is attaching all the files together. How can i fix that?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

tabela = pd.read_excel('SepEmpresa.xlsx')

olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
caminho = 'C:\ArquivosPDF\OK'

for i, Vencidos in enumerate(table['Vencidos']):
    if Vencidos == 'OK':
        email = tabela.loc[i, 'Email']
        mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        mailItem.Display()
        mailItem.Subject = 'Expired'
        mailItem.Body = 'anything'
        mailItem.To = email
        path = "C:/ArquivosPDF/OK"
        dirs = os.listdir(path)
        for files in dirs:
            mailItem.Attachments.Add(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), caminho, files))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your list of companies is contained in `table['Vencidos']`, then for each company in that table, you are looping over all files in the path specified (`path = "C:/ArquivosPDF/OK"`).

In other words, this:

```py
    for files in dirs:
            mailItem.Attachments.Add(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), caminho, files))
```

happens for all companies where `table['Vencidos']=="OK"`. It sounds like that's not your desired behaviour.

If there is a single document contained in `path` that you want to attach for a particular company, then you'll have to find a way to associate that file for that company.

In pseudo-code:

```py
for i, Vencidos in enumerate(table['Vencidos']):
    # set up email/mailItem objects

    # get the specific file attachment for that company
    file_to_attach = os.path.join(caminho, "file_for_company_A.pdf")

    mailItem.Attachments.Add(file_to_attach)
```